# How secure is downloading Tor from a PPA vs. from official website?

Tags: security, ubuntu, debian, update

I use Tor browser on Ubuntu and every time it updates, I have to download and unpack the binaries again. This is a bit annoying, so I would prefer to use a PPA. I found [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/tor-browser) by the webupd8team, but how safe is it to install from this source when compared from installing from the Tor website. Has the Tor foundation released an official word on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I see it, the [package file](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/tor-browser/+packages) brings its own version of the Tor Browser Bundle. So if you want to make sure that someone didn't change anything you'd have to check the integrity for yourself. If you don't do this the maintainer can inject arbitrary code into his TBB version.

A better way would be to download the TBB archive directly from torproject.org and check its integrity. This way you can be sure that you receive an unmodified version.

If you just care about updating TBB, I would recommend [`torbrowser-launcher`](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher) ([Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=torbrowser-launcher)). This downloads TBB is a safe way and updates your installation.